# In angularjs, when making a directive, is there a way to manipulate the DOM of the template using the link function?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

Let's say I'm creating a dynamic directive in angularjs. I want to use the link function to manipulate the DOM of the template html based on the arguments.

So in vanilla javascript, I would do something like the following:

```
var template = ... //something here that sets the variable to the template
var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
template.appendChild(newdiv);
```

I found some answers where they treat the template like a string and just splice in the literal string `"<div></div>"`.

However, I plan to do a lot of modification so treating it as a string will quickly get too confusing, and will be unmaintainable if I do it. If possible, I would like to treat it the same way I treat the page's DOM in regular js.

I am also open to having no template, and just dynamically generating the whole thing in the link function, if it's possible for me to somehow get the directive to return this

Comment: `link` is there exactly for this. Template will create data bindings automatically, manually added elements won't have this feature. There is a good chance that you have XY problem, and the template should be refactored into several directives to stop being 'confusing'.

Comment: It's okay if there's no data binding, the directive won't be changed once it's made. Just how do I make the directive dynamic based on arguments rather than return the same html every time

Comment: There is a lot of possibilities, e.g. [component `template` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#component) that can be injected with `$attrs` to make decisions on the template string. The preferable way depends on the case. `ng-if` or `ng-include` may work as well. I would suggest to update the question with details on what exactly the directive is supposed to do, this may help to get a quality answer.

Comment: For now, all I want to do is figure out how to add an addition div to the root div of the template. That's it. Once I figure this out, I can do the rest

Comment: To add to the *template* before it is compiled, `element` in `compile` function can be modified. To add to compiled template, it is `element` in `link`.

Comment: Yes, that much I know. I want to do it after it's compiled using element in link. But I can't find anything on how exactly I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiled element can be modified in [`link` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-). No bindings or directives can be added to the element at this point without recompilation.

```
...
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  // jqLite element that partly implements jQuery API
  element.append(...);

  // native element that is wrapped with jqLite
  var nativeElement = element[0];
  nativeElement.appendChild(...);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but my question has to do with how exactly I would add nativeElement to element. element.append(nativeElement) doesn't work

Comment: It should. `append` accepts several types, including DOM elements, it follows jQuery APi here. If `nativeElement` is the same element as `element`, it will obviously not work. Please, provide a reproducible example (a plunker or so) if you will have problems with this.